# Using Visual Studio Code Python extension with Jupyter interactive window on a Retina display

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, retina-display

Is there a way to instruct the Jupiter interactive window to use a Retina display with the Python extension of Visual Studio Code? For example, this minimal code

```
#%%
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
```

produces an output that shows clearly the image pixels (note the resolution difference between the text "matplotlib.lines.Line2D..." and the plot markers):

[image: output of the code]

Using the standard line

```
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
```

unfortunately does not seem to solve the problem: it makes images twice as large, but still not retina-display ready.

Comment: Marco. I'm on the dev team for this feature and we had not yet tested the 'retina' figure_format. It does in deed look incorrect to me, it's sharper on my screen, but still looks to be scaling up the image which reduces the resolution bump. I've filed a GitHub issue in our repo to fix this. You can track it here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4466

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the setting `%config InlineBackend.figure_format='svg'`, it seems to have the best resolution without the scaling issue.